# Empty variable gives true value to disabled attribute on input

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular2-ngmodel

I dont know if this is a problem or normal behavior.

If we have a form like this:

```
<form #form="ngForm" >
  <div>
     <label>field1</label>
     <input type="text" name="field1" [(ngModel)]="mainVar" [disabled]="someVar"  />                                                                                                                    
  </div>
  <div>
     <label>field2</label>
     <input type="text" name="field2" [(ngModel)]="someVar" />
  </div>
</form>
```

In the same time variables **mainVar** and **someVar** are set to empty string in the component:

```
mainVar = '';
someVar = '';
```

This will result in input with name **field1** being disabled, even though **someVar** is empty string. To my knowledge, variable that is empty string, should return *false* to if statement.

But the strangest thing is that if i remove **[(ngModel)]** attribute from input **field1**, it will work as it should (input **field1** will be disabled if I type something into input **field2**)

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/x2QTX33HwXeA8UZdxJr7?p=preview)

Comment: Boolean attributes don't give consideration to their value. If the attribute is present, it means `true`.

Comment: Check out [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in javascript.. empty string is considered falsy.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. But why does it behave opposite to what you say if i remove [(ngModel)]

Comment: @suraj , that is what i said up in the example, that empty string should return false

Comment: `[disabled]="''"` will return `true`, the true mystery is why is it working when you remove the model.

Comment: `[disabled]="someVar.length"` seems to work: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lkq1FdXM2CryZ8jVbigf?p=preview

Comment: @Pete that is only one of many workarounds. Since 0 and '' both return false, it should work in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### UPDATE

**I found the answer to this in the angular source code** (<3 open source!). The `ngModel` controller explicitly checks for `''` when the `disabled input` is changed. If the input strictly equals `''`, the element will be disabled. So this behavior is by design.

Here is how to source code looks ([link to GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5efc86069ff92d980bb460c15deccb1e0fff9363/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts), see line 142 and 217)

```
const isDisabled = disabledValue === '' || (disabledValue && disabledValue !== 'false');
```

**This means that you cannot use an empty string as falsy** to set an input that is using `ngModel` to disable it.

Here is how you get around it

```
<input type="text" name="field1" [(ngModel)]="mainVar" [disabled]="someVar ? true : false"  />
```

[**Working plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/yee17WfzOrQ3JLwx8ATl?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is still Angular problem

Comment: @maxal90, if you truly believe this is a bug you should file an issue at the official github repo

Comment: I thought about that also, if the empty string is present it should give attribute by the rules of the HTML. But if you set 0 as a value for someVar, field1 will not be disabled. And 0 is the same as empty string false in if statement

Comment: i just did  make a issue there. Hope it will get an answer. Thanks anyway

Comment: @maxal90: Well, `0` is falsy, `'0'` is not falsy

Comment: @maxal90, see update, I found the answer in the source code

Comment: Perfect! I guess the documentation has to be updated on this.

Comment: @Nirus yea, I'm not finding it in the docs at all tbh. Not sure why this check is added either

Comment: @Fredrik Lundin , i just saw your updated answer. 
This is very interesting. Actually i was looking for it in the source code, but didnt find the file :D Great find.
I agree that this check is not needed at all. Hope they remove it soon

Answer (score -2):

Set it to null/undefined/false, and it will not be disabled.
String empty is still a value.

Comment: I know, if i do double negation !!someVar i will get boolean value, but why does it behave differently if [(ngModel)] is removed

Comment: empty string value is false https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: The question is about angular, not Mozilla specifications.