# how to check button is disable or not in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to add unit test cases of `template driven form`. How to check `submit` button is **disabled** at initial stage and `enable` when when user enter all valid `field` .

Here is form

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8q2zr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Unit test case

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-5m3qwm?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed,async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }  from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


//
describe('AppComponent', () => {
   let fixture ,component,debugElement; 
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(()=>{
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
  })

  xdescribe('initial state of form',()=>{

    it('form is invalide button is disable',()=>{
    // fixture.detectChanges();
   //   debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
   //   expect(true).toBe(true)
    })
  })


})
```

Any update ?

Comment: it's not easy to test template driven forms, it's better to use model driven forms they are easy to test

Comment: @fetch mohamed yes model driven is easy ,  but I want to know how I will test `template driven` form

Comment: It's a little dirty but you can use `setItnterval` and inside it, check whether your form is valid or not, if valid, call `clearInterval` and continue ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the submit-button by using:

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type=submit]'))
```

and to check if it is disabled you use the nativeElement of it:

```
describe('initial state of form',()=>{

    it('form is invalide button is disable',()=>{
      let submitEL: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type=submit]'));
      expect(submitEL.nativeElement.disabled).toBe(true);
    })
  })
```

Comment: thanks for answering one more can we check submit button is "enabled" when form is valid ?

Comment: mean we we enter valid entries can in form then button is enabled can we check this

Comment: Depending on what status you want to check you can just change the expected value in the toBe() function. If its enabled then it is not disabled and therefore it should be expect(submitEL.nativeElement.disabled).toBe(false)

Comment: so how i will provide value to form .currently `expect(submitEL.nativeElement.disabled).toBe(true)` it true  because form element don't have values

Comment: how I will pass value in `name` and `email` to check `button status` or check you expect(submitEL.nativeElement.disabled).toBe(false)

Comment: You need to bind your form to a variable in the component. You can read [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/forms/template-driven/) how to do that. After that you can just set the values by using component.youModelName.yourAtributename = value

Comment: Did the answer solve your initial question? @user944513

Comment: In my case, it does not work, even if the select is enabled (disabled="" in html), the test passes `expect(mySelect.nativeElement.disabled).toBe(true);`

Comment: @IslamMurtazaev setting disabled to an empty string makes the element disabled https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231752/empty-variable-gives-true-value-to-disabled-attribute-on-input/43232499

Comment: does not work for me, in Angular8. I get this error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null